# Display Text Over Image Using Div in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried displaying text over an image with the code below like the following;

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="https://cdn0.vox-   cdn.com/thumbor/qLH7593e3D2SSSIdkwgBWdYhjjk=/289x0:802x684/400x533/filters:forma t(webp)/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47859707/6621139883_e6be6a217a_b__1_.0.0.jpg"  alt="" />
 <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Restaurant Stowaway Devours $800 of Roast Goose and Wine</h2>

 </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;  
}

.wrapper img {
   display: block;
   max-width:100%;
}

.wrapper .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    color:white;
}
```

But it comes out like this: 
[image]

Please help me, what have I missed? Because I want the output to be like the first image that I have shown above.

Comment: Create a div element , which has that image as a background!!!! , after that add the text in another div box. Try to resize the width and move it to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add class to your header h2 tag and add the following style to it.
Add the following class,

```
 <h2 class="header">Restaurant Stowaway Devours $800 of Roast Goose and Wine</h2>

h2.header {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```